# Can't find directory created by using sqlplus console

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, directory, create-directory

I created a directory using SQLPlus console but I cant find it on file system. Here is the command I used:

```
SQL> create directory secfile as ’/opt/oracle’;

Directory created.
```

I have looked in my Oracle home directory(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle`) but there is no 'images' folder.
Where should I look for it?

I'm using Oracle 11g Data Base(installed on my C drive) and I need this directory to store pictures which I will be further storing in the data base. I was following a tutorial about storing pictures on OracleDB in which ’/opt/oracle’ patch were used for that directory.

Comment: Not directly relevant, but I wouldn't put an OS folder in the Oracle hierarchy; ideally the Oracle software and data files would be on different filesystems to everything else to prevent your DB running into space issues caused by other activity on the server. That may not be an option, but I'd at least separate them logically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have things the wrong way around. You need to create a directory in the operating system, and then create an Oracle directory object using the full path to the operating system directory. The Oracle `create directory` command only creates a data dictionary object, it does not itself do anything on your server's file system. And you can't use a relative path.

Well, you *can* create them in either order, but the operating system directory has to have been created by the time you try to use the Oracle one, so to me it makes more sense to create that first.

Comment: Oh, I get the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `CREATE DIRECTORY` command does not create a directory on your server's disc. It creates a directory object in your Oracle database which serves as a "pointer" (if you will) to a directory on your disc, and until some code running in your database (for example, some PL/SQL code) tries to use the directory object the database will not know or care if the directory actually exists on the disc. YOU have to create the disc directory, using either Windows Explorer or the Windows command line.

Best of luck.