# Unable to load data using external table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I'm trying to load data in an external table from a csv file.
Following is my fragment:

```
create table emp_ext
(
eid number,ename char(9)
)
organization external
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY test
ACCESS PARAMETERS
       (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       (
       eid number,
       ename char(9)
       )

       )
       LOCATION('C:\Users\99002971\Desktop\empf.csv')
)

create directory test as 'C:\Users\99002971\Desktop'
grant read on directory test to matuat35 // granted using another user
```

When i do select * from emp_ext , i get following errors:

```
ORA-29913:Error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400:data cartridge error
KUP-00554:error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005:syntax error:found ""identifier:expecting one of :"binary_float,binary_double,comma,char,date,double"
KUP-01008:the bad identifier was double
KUP-01007:at line 4 column 12
```

Please help

Comment: The location should just be the filename within the directory, not the full path, so just `'empf.csv'`. Does it give the same error when that is corrected?

Comment: i did that earlier ,i got 
ORA-29913:Error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400:data cartridge error
KUP-00554:error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005:syntax error:found "error":expecting one of :"column,enclosed,(,ltrim,lrtrim,notrim,optionally,reject"
KUP-01007:at line 3 column 10
KUP-0031:Message 31 not found;product=RDBMS;facility=KUP

Comment: i'v a doubt ,when creating directory object,oracle lets you select a path ,where i selected 'C:\Users\99002971\Desktop' which is on my local machine. It's not actually creating a directory there.

Comment: Oracle's `create directory` command only creates an object in the data dictionary, [it doesn't create an operating system directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26557343/266304). You can also only access directories on the database server; if Oracle is running on your PC that's OK, but if it's on another machine somewhere then it can't access your client PC's local drive.

Comment: ok,but while creating the directory object it asks for path and that;s on local machine.ok ,then it won't create an O.S directory,but what about the error? i posted the new one after changing location();

Comment: I have no idea what code you were running when you got the message about `error`. The code in my answer works. When you create the directory the path you give has to be on the database server, not on your client PC; and that path has to exist on the server, and be accessible by the Oracle operating system account..

Comment: Thanks Alex,for the clarification it worked,now getting fake data in the external table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*`datatype_spec`* section of the external table documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1420) shows that `number` isn't recognised by the loader driver. In your code that is being seen as an identifier rather than a data type, hence the error.

You can use `oracle_number`, or `unsigned integer` since it's presumably always going to be a positive integer for an employee ID; or leave it untyped and allow implicit conversion to the table column type.

Your `location` should also only specify the file name within the directory, not the full path:

```
create table emp_ext
(
eid number,ename varchar2(15)
)
organization external
(
TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
DEFAULT DIRECTORY test
ACCESS PARAMETERS
       (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       (
       eid unsigned integer external(9),
       ename char(15)
       )

       )
       LOCATION('empf.csv')
)
```

Or more simply, but relying on implicit conversion:

```
...
ACCESS PARAMETERS
       (
       RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       (
       eid,
       ename char(15) rteim
       )

       )
       LOCATION('empf.csv')
)
```

Comment: tried both,for oracle_number - column type not supported on external organized table
for unsigned integer, i used 
create table emp_ext
    (
    eid  unsigned integer ,ename VARCHAR2(15)
    ) 
error-missing right parenthesis

Comment: Look at the code I posted; I only changed the data type in the access parameters' `fields` section, *not* in the table's column list. (Though changing the table's `char` to `varchar2` is probably a good idea).

Comment: I changed code to 
    organization external
    (
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY test
    ACCESS PARAMETERS
           (
           RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
           FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
          (
           eid unsigned integer,
           ename char(15)
           )    )
           LOCATION('empf.csv')
    ) 
Now i got : 
ORA-29913:Error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400:data cartridge error
KUP-00554:error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005:syntax error:found"minussign" : expecting one of "column"
KUP-01007 at line 7 column 9

Comment: @arjungaur - I'd left out the `external` clause. (It's simpler to specify no data type and left it implicitly convert...). If you still get an error then please add your CSV file contents to the question.

Comment: I got it worker now,was using a wrong directory path :but now am getting 
wrong data in table:
'empf.csv' contains 
1,arjun
2,ankit
3,gaur
Table after loading contains:
    EID ENAME
1 824992114 "jun
           "
2 841769316 "as
            "
3 858552164 "fdf
           "

Comment: Is it because of 'char' ? As per the doc you shared i changed my code to:
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
          (
           eid unsigned integer,
           ename varchar(15)
           )
Now am getting error "reject limit reached"

Comment: @arjungaur - that looks like you didn't add the `external(9)` part of the datatype specification, so it's interpreting your first column as a binary value. (The `9` should reflect the maximum number of digits you'll ever have in the `eid` column. Again, letting it do implicit conversion is simpler.)

Comment: Thanks,leaving out the datatype for eid ,worked and got the correct data,now just don't know how to get varchar to work,cause with char my length(ename) is returning 15 and thereby inserting spaces. ,i'v loaded data using Control files ,just wanted to see how external table works ,so i'm basically new to this.Just doing some research

Comment: Should be OK with the table column defined as `varchar2(15)`. Do you have spaces after the name in your file? If so, and you can't remove them, you can [trim the whitespace during load](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_params.htm#SUTIL1411).

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex,it worked after changing table column type.
The datatypes we specify in 'FIELDS' clause specifies the type of data in my csv file,right?

Comment: As for the trim spec,i could even create a procedure to perform validations like trim,rounding off etc and then load the data in my main table from the external table,I could use it as a staging table.